# GitHub Forked Repository doesn't update after pull (or fetch and merge)

Tags: github, fork, fetch

I'm new to GitHub, but I read every possible help section and many StackOverflow posts and I still don't have the answer I'm looking for. (Btw I removed the https:// in front of the links because of lack of rep points, but in the original they are present).

There is the repository I want to sync my files with - github.com/Something/project.git

I forked it. Then I cloned my fork to my computer using Git Bash:

> git clone github.com/MY_USERNAME/project.git

I opened the folder:

> cd project/

I added as a second remote the repository:

> git remote add upstream github.com/Something/project.git

I downloaded its files:

> git fetch upstream

Now I have:

```
git remote -v
origin github.com/MY_USERNAME/project.git (fetch)
origin github.com/MY_USERNAME/project.git (push)
upstream github.com/Something/project.git (fetch)
upstream github.com/Something/project.git (push)
```

And here comes the problem. **Let's say I deleted some files from my computer and from my fork. And the main repository doesn't have new updates meanwhile.** I try to download original files again and to update my fork using:

```
git fetch upstream master
git merge upstream/master
```

But NOTHING updates. I get only Allready up-to-date all the time!!! I tried many different "ways" including pull. I tried to "change" the branch with checkout, but I don't have any others, so nothing happens again. There is only one branch in the original repository and only one in mine, so it's not the problem. **Btw I push my files to the fork without any problem!**

So the question is: What does it mean to [sync the fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork), when it doesn't even download. **Is it possible to directly update my fork, without having to update first my local files and then upload to my fork?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't update because you already have every commit from upstream in your hostory. If you deleted some files and commited the changes that means you are ahead.

Comment: If I want to "fix" my fork which I somehow corrupted, do I have to download eveything as .zip from the original project, unpack files on my computer and upload as commit to my fork?

Comment: If by fix you mean get back to the point where upstream is, the answer is no. just check the hash of the last commit from your `upstream/<branch>` and then run `git reset <hash> --hard` (but remember that this will delete your changes permanently)

Comment: Oh, this looks too easy after I spent my last 5 hours with this matter :D

Comment: "HEAD is now at ..." - now what comes? I've never used it. It still doesn't change.

Comment: If you've reset to the right point that'd be it. What does `git status` says?

Comment: This is kind of overwrite? Won't do anything unless I commit new changes? But if this is the case, then I cannot achieve my goal -> to get my files back.

Git status says: nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: This is kind of rewinding. You are getting back to the state where your upstream is. If you've deleted tracked files they are still in the repo and will appear in your work dir if you checkout some commit before deletion. If you didn't track them you can't get them back.

Comment: I finally did it. I had to choose the hash number of the last useful commit and then use your code: git reset <hash> --hard . After this I need to push using -f: git push -f origin master